# Does vue.js have something like AngularJS' `ng-repeat-start`

Tags: vue.js

Parsing vue.js' docs I can't see any hint that vue.js has something like a `ng-repeat-start` / `ng-repeat-end`

Is there a way to archive something like

```
<table>

  <tr class="weather_warning top" ng-repeat-start="warning in dwd_warnings">
    <td {{warning.valid_from}} → {{warning.valid_to}}</td>
    <td><div style='background:{{warning.color}};'>{{warning.message}}</div></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="weather_warning bottom" ng-repeat-end>
    <td colspan="2">
      {{warning.description}}<br/>
      <span>Issued on the {{warning.effective}} ({{warning.headline}}). {{warning.ascertain}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Each warning consists of 2 TRs which go together. One is the top half of the message in the iteration, the other one the lower half. It must be this way, because of some very weird formatting stuff, so there's no way around using 2 TRs for one item. Maybe some tags are off in this example, this is because I had to delete a ton of stuff in order to post it here. Note the `colspan="2"` in the TD of the second TR, which might give a bit of a hint of the problem which is tackled here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing I can think of is to use a `<template>`, eg

```html
<template v-for="item in items">
  <header>
    Header {{ item }}
  </header>
  <div class="body">
    Body {{ item }}
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer {{ item }}
  </footer>
</template
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

> ... you can also use a `<template>` tag with `v-for` to render a block of multiple elements

---

Nothing changes with your edit, you just wrap your two `<tr>` elements in

```html
<template v-for="warning in dwd_warnings">
  <tr class="weather_warning top">
    <!-- etc -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="weather_warning bottom">
    <!-- etc -->
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: @DanielF I think not, at least according to the example here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points

Comment: I removed my comment, because I saw the error. I'm updating the question now to reflect my specific use-case, give me a minute

Comment: I changed the example. As I said, when I commented, I did so erroneously, with a wrong assumption, please check the question again and you will understand my problem.

Comment: @DanielF I've updated my answer though nothing has really changed

Comment: Does this mean that the `<template>` tag won't be rendered at all? That I get a consecutive chain of TRs for multiple elements?

Comment: @DanielF that's correct. Have a good read of the documentation I linked including following [the links](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt)

Comment: Just note: you need to specify ":key" property for child elements, not the template tag.